# 12.04 LTS to 14.01.1 LTS

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, upgrade

I hate asking questions on these forums simply because I know it has been asked and answered somewhere else, but after hours of looking I cannot find an acceptable solution to my question.

I am trying to upgrade from 12.04 LTS to 14.04.1 LTS using the command:

```
 sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Since it is now August 2nd and the 14.04.1 release came out on July 25th, the above command should do what is expected (upgrade the system to 14.04 LTS), but it does not. Instead I get the dreaded:

```
 Checking for a new Ubuntu release
 No new release found
```

I do not want to use:

```
  do-release-upgrade -d
```

Simply because I shouldn't have to and I don't want to deal with the 1 in 1,000,000 chance that I will get the non-LTS update that breaks my system (my luck says it will happen).

So, what is going on, and how do I fix it? Again, please don't suggest that I use:

```
 sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

because I shouldn't have to and I don't want to. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: I'm new to Ubuntu. I'm confused by this question, as i downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 some one month ago from Ubuntu site.
And I'm clear now that Why I don't get any answers in any forum regarding installing my zte 1x cdma modem in ubuntu 14.04.
I'll be thankful If anybody help me

Comment: I've been thinking about this for a while though, but there doesn't seem to have been any "official" answers to this question yet. Hope someone could give an authoritative answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There still is a problem with the `grub` package for upgrades into 14.04. Both upgrades from 13.10 and 12.04 show the same problems. This is a major issue for production systems.

Here is the current bug report in launchpad, you may follow this to get updates to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1289977

Here is an unanswered question, upgrading from 12.04 with Windows dual-boot. The user used `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` and it messes up: https://askubuntu.com/questions/471869/grub-rescue-prompt-file-not-found-after-update-12-04-lts-14-04-lts-through-u

That means that those who would like to upgrade must be a little more patient while this bug is still being fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There were some last minute bugs which delayed the release.  Look for the 14.04.1  release on Thurs and Fri (maybe next week if lucky).  Better to get the LTS release right than cause problems.

Comment: Well hell, that's the simplest answer I could have asked for, thank you. Why then does http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2014/07/25/ubuntu-14-04-1-lts-released/ clearly say that it has been released? I do believe you by the way, I am just curious about the inconsistency.

Comment: Is there no answer for why the entire internet says that the point version is out, but I still can't upgrade using do-release-upgrade?

Comment: Yes is it out, you can download and use it.  What is held up it the network upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04.